# using packer vmware-vmx and provisioning a machine that does not support ssh with password

Tags: security, vmware, devops, packer, packer-builder

Using the vmware-vmx builder I don't see a way to specify the SSH private key to use. The only options I see are:

```
ssh_username
ssh_password
```

SSH access using passwords are disabled and I only allow public key SSH. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [ssh_private_key_file](https://packer.io/docs/templates/communicator.html#ssh_private_key_file).